# PDP 11 - how to know the Op Code of branch commands

Tags: assembly, branch, opcode, pdp-11

I'm having some problems in understanding how to get the right opCode of Branch commands.
lets say the command :

```
beq .+40
```

the beq opCode is `001400` 
I know that the two last characters in the opCode suppose to include the offset we need to jump. 
In the answers for this question, it is written `001417` but I dont understand why, how did they get the `17` from `40` ? 
Would appericiate a brief explenation.

Comment: 40 (octal) is 32, 17 (octal) is 15. Note that the stored offset is multiplied by 2, so 15 becomes 30. Then there's still two unexplained bytes, I would guess that the instruction measure the offset from the position *after* the branch while the assembly code measures the offset from the *start* of the branch.

Comment: I think harold is right.  17 octal is 0b001111 the offset is multiplied by 2 before being added to the pc so that makes it 0b0011110 add 2 for this instruction, and you get 0b0100000 which is 40.  Many architectures the offset is applied to the pc after the instruction (think of the pc being used to fetch the instruction bytes, by the time the instruction gets to decode and execute the pc is pointing at the byte after the instruction).

Answer (score 1):

The PDP-11 Programming card writes :
New PC <- Updated PC + (2 x offset)
and
Updated PC = Address of br instruction + 2.
Note : (2 x offset) means that the offset is counted in 16 bits words.

All calculation are in octal.

You read 001417. 17 is the offset (lower 8 bits).
New PC = Updated PC + (2 x 17) = Updated PC + 36
Updated PC = 2, and 2 + 36 = 40.

So the disassembly of the word "001417" reads "br .+40".

From "br .+40" you can also notice that 40 / 2 = 20 (words) and 20 - 1 = 17 words.

Source : http://www.jfc.org.uk/documents/scandoc.php?page=4&maxpage=10%0A&dir=pdp11%2Fpdp11